# kSecClass.takeRetainedValue() error in xcode6 beta 2

Tags: swift, xcode6

I am getting error when I run  `var kSecAttrAccessGroupSwift: NSString = kSecClass.takeRetainedValue() as NSString`

The error Description is :

> Bitcast requires both operands to be pointer or neither   %182 =
>   bitcast %objc_object* %181 to %PSs9AnyObject_, !dbg !247 Bitcast
>   requires both operands to be pointer or neither   %183 = bitcast
>   %PSs9AnyObject_ %182 to i8*, !dbg !247 LLVM ERROR: Broken function
>   found, compilation aborted! Command
>   /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift
>   failed with exit code 1

I am running xCode6 beta 2 , what is the reason for this error, is this a bug ?

Comment: it's a bug, report it.

Answer (score 1):

you must do this!!

```
var kSecAttrAccessGroupSwift = NSString(format: kSecClass)
```

Comment: Can you please explain more your answer ?

Comment: Call let kSecClassValue = kSecClass.takeRetainedValue () as NSString will generate an error because the class kSecClass no method takeRetainedValue () and therefore constant declaration kSekslassValue should look like this as I have described above